# IntelliJ - Have "Reformat Code" remove unnecessary HTML newlines in text?

Tags: html, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Using "Reformat Code" in IntelliJ (and other JetBrains IDEs) on an HTML file will add newlines in text to ensure that text does not go beyond the right margin. What I'm looking for is the ability to have a portion of the text be moved back to the previous line if there is space for it on the previous line.

For example, if I originally have:

```
<p>
    This is some text that is fairly long and won't fit on a single line without going over the right margin.
</p>
```

Reformatting the code results in something like (assuming a very small right margin):

```
<p>
    This is some text that is fairly long and
    won't fit on a single line without going
    over the right margin.
</p>
```

But then if I remove some text:

```
<p>
    This is some text that
    won't fit on a single line without going
    over the right margin.
</p>
```

I would like reformatting the code to automatically result in this:

```
<p>
    This is some text that won't fit on a
    single line without going over the right
    margin.
</p>
```

I looked through the settings for reformatting code, but did not see how to do this. Possibly one of the "Keep newlines" options, but removing those seemed to remove newlines between tags as well. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Intellij has code style option called 'Keep line breaks in text' for HTML. Disable that option, and then reformat code.

[image]